# Sonarqube treat AOP Throwable as an issue

Tags: java, sonarqube, aop

Sonarqube defines a rule saying **Generic exceptions should never be thrown** (i.e. throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.)
However AOP **ProceedingJoinPoint** always throws generic **Throwable** and normally I am not interested in the exception at all and just throw it from the method like this:

```
@Around(...)
public void someMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    // do something...
    point.proceed();
    // do something else...
}
```

Obviously this is against the above-mentioned Sonarqube rule. Do I really have to wrapper it with try catch and log the throwable or something? What is the best practice on this?

Comment: as alternative you can try add exclusion to your pom.xml file:<sonar.exclusions>**/aspects/**</sonar.exclusions> , where *aspects* is the name of destination package

Comment: exclusions is evil, it makes Sonar skip the whole file, not only a particular violation

Comment: Thanks for your answers however I am more towards @spi about marking it  as false positive for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely mark this violation as a **false positive** and enter a descriptive comment. This kind of false positive should be rare enough to allow you to treat them individualy, and act accordingly - AoP API is a good example, legacy and/or badly written libraries is another. But do NOT add the files to exclusions, as you would loose other rules from the Sonar analysis

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you can't avoid to use libraries that throw `Throwable` or plain `Exception`s themselves. So there will always be an offend of that rule form sonarqube when you treat this Exception.

But you should definitely catch this Exception and do something with it. What exactly you do with it depends of the layer of your application that is catching it. If it's a lower one then you probably might want to wrap it into your own proper Exception. Consider that all other higher layers don't want to know which dependencies you use. If you are a high layer yourself then you could log it or return a proper message for the user. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In the someMethod() we have implemented proper exception handling. This AOP is more about gathering some metrics and should be disposable. We do not intend it to have any business logic involving the method itself even logging. I am going to take @spi 's advice about marking it as false positive.

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do anyway to satisfy sonarqube.